# Is there any benefit to splitting DECLARE into two parts in a SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I've seen code that looks like this in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR (64),
        @var2 NVARCHAR (64),
        @Var3 NVARCHAR(512);

DECLARE @Var4 AS INT,
        @Var5 AS INT,
        @Var6 AS INT,
        @Var7 nvarchar(32);
```

Is there any benefit to declaring them that way, as opposed to just putting them all inside one DECLARE statement as below?

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR (64),
        @var2 NVARCHAR (64),
        @Var3 NVARCHAR(512),
        @Var4 AS INT,
        @Var5 AS INT,
        @Var6 AS INT,
        @Var7 nvarchar(32);
```

Comment: Readability? Grouping variable declarations based on usage e.g. constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readability like `T I` mentioned is probably the most important one. There can be advantages and disadvantages when using initializers. Using values of previously declared vars must be in separate statements. Only when initializers are applied there is big performance difference between the two options below. Option A runs twice as fast.

### Option A

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @time DATETIME2(7) = SYSDATETIME();
WHILE @i < 10000000
BEGIN
    DECLARE @A CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @B CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @C CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @D CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @E CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @F CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @G CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @H CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @J CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @K CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
          , @L CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS';

    SET @i += 1;
END
PRINT DATEDIFF(ms, @time, SYSDATETIME());
```

### Option B

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @time DATETIME2(7) = SYSDATETIME();
WHILE @i < 10000000
BEGIN
    DECLARE @A CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @B CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @C CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @D CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @E CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @F CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @G CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @H CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @J CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @K CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS'
    DECLARE @L CHAR(1000) = 'ASDGASDGASGDSAGSADGASGS';

    SET @i += 1;
END
PRINT DATEDIFF(ms, @time, SYSDATETIME());
```